# using awk to do left outer join kinda sql on files in unix

Tags: unix, join, awk

I'm trying to do a join based on the 1st columns present in both the files.

So far I have tried using is the below code

```
awk  '{if (NR==FNR) {a[$1]=$2; next} if ($1 in a) {print $2"|"$3"|""Found"}      if(!($1 in a)) {print $2"|"$3"|""Not Found"}}' file1.txt file2.txt > TARGET.txt

file1 file contents
1as.pdf
2as.pdf
3as.pdf
45.pdf
as.pdf

file2 file contents
3ss.pdf 1_2_3_45.csv    4
3s.pdf  1_2_3_45.csv    4
2as.pdf 1_2_3_45.csv    4
1as.pdf 1_2_3_45.csv    4
45.pdf  1_2_3_45_5.csv  1
3.pdf   1_2_3_5.csv 1
```

Comment: You know there's a unix command called [`join`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=join)?

Comment: yep @WumpusQ.Wumbley but for join to be performed the files should be in sorted order and sorting lines for ex : 100,000 would be costlier i feel so i selected the awk way

Comment: Hi. What is your question? Please read & act on [mcve]. PS What does "costlier" mean? What do you think the costs are? Suggest you look into them.

Comment: @philipxy my aim was to do left outer join using awk command not with join and from other blog i have learnt that awk is faster than join while processing 100,000 lines of a file.

Comment: awk is not an algorithm. Details of algorithms & overheads matter. Your program does 10k x 10k row comparisons. Join on sorted does  ~ a comparison per output row, likely a *tiny* fraction of 10k x 10k, plus 2 sorts, each 10k x ~ log2(10k) = 10k x 50 comparisons, another tiny fraction. Memory vs file use is also important. So are table constraints. Suggest you read an introduction to algorithm costs (complexity) in a computer science introductory textbook. Suggest you actually measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -v OFS='|' 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} 
                         {print $2,$3,(($1 in a)?"Found":"Not Found")}' file1 file2 

1_2_3_45.csv|4|Not Found
1_2_3_45.csv|4|Not Found
1_2_3_45.csv|4|Found
1_2_3_45.csv|4|Found
1_2_3_45_5.csv|1|Found
1_2_3_5.csv|1|Not Found
```

however, since you're not printing the key, what's is found, what is not found is not very clear.  Perhaps keep the first field in the output as well...

Comment: could you explain me the {a[$1];next} please

Comment: you have in your code as well.  Adding `$1` from file1 to the hash table `a` in order to check existence while scanning file2.  Note that you set to `$2` which doesn't exist, even if did, it won't be used so no need to assign it.